# How do I optimize this query? It's taking 3 minutes to run

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, optimization

I have a database with 3 tables.

1. A `calendar` table that has a row for each date between `2000-01-01` and `2040-01-01` totaling 14610 rows
2. A `locations` table that has an `id` and `name` for each location totaling 12 rows
3. A `receipts` table that has an `id` and `datetime`, and several other fields that aren't relevant totaling ~250,000 rows

I'm trying to get a count of `receipts` for each day between a date range grouped by location with zero counts if no receipts exist.

I've got a working query but it takes ~3 minutes to run:

```
SELECT
    `locations`.`name` AS `location`,
    `calendar`.`date` AS `date`,
    COUNT(`receipts`.`id`) AS `count`
FROM `locations`
    CROSS JOIN `calendar`
    LEFT JOIN `receipts` ON `calendar`.`date` = DATE(`receipts`.`datetime`)
        AND `locations`.`id` = UPPER(LEFT(`receipts`.`id`, 1)) # there is no `location_id` FK. First char of receipts id is same as location id
WHERE `calendar`.`date` >= '2017-04-01' AND `calendar`.`date` <= '2017-04-07'
GROUP BY `locations`.`id`, `calendar`.`id`
ORDER BY `locations`.`name` ASC, `calendar`.`date` ASC;
```

I believe it has something to do with the `WHERE` statement.

I changed the `WHERE` to this instead which runs instantly but it no longer gives me zero counts for no receipts:

```
SELECT
    `locations`.`name` AS `location`,
    `calendar`.`date` AS `date`,
    COUNT(`receipts`.`id`) AS `count`
FROM `locations`
    CROSS JOIN `calendar`
    LEFT JOIN `receipts` ON `calendar`.`date` = DATE(`receipts`.`datetime`)
        AND `locations`.`id` = UPPER(LEFT(`receipts`.`id`, 1)) # there is no `location_id` FK. First char of receipts id is same as location id
WHERE DATE(`receipts`.`datetime`) >= '2017-04-01' AND DATE(`receipts`.`datetime`) <= '2017-04-07'
GROUP BY `locations`.`id`, `calendar`.`id`
ORDER BY `locations`.`name` ASC, `calendar`.`date` ASC;
```

I then started messing around with subqueries but no success:

```
SELECT
    `locations`.`name` AS `location`,
    `cal`.`date` AS `date`,
    COUNT(`receipts`.`id`) AS `count`
FROM `locations`
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT `calendar`.`id`, `calendar`.`date`
        FROM `calendar`
        WHERE `calendar`.`date` >= '2017-04-01' AND `calendar`.`date` <= '2017-04-07'
    ) `cal`
    LEFT JOIN `receipts` ON `cal`.`date` = DATE(`receipts`.`datetime`)
        AND `locations`.`id` = UPPER(LEFT(`receipts`.`id`, 1)) # there is no `location_id` FK. First char of receipts id is same as location id
WHERE DATE(`receipts`.`datetime`) >= '2017-04-01' AND DATE(`receipts`.`datetime`) <= '2017-04-07'
GROUP BY `locations`.`id`, `cal`.`id`
ORDER BY `locations`.`name` ASC, `cal`.`date` ASC;
```

Anyway I can speed up the first query since that's the one that gives me the output I want?

Comment: I think the String comparison here is causing the slowdown, could you consider adding a foreign key?

Comment: Do you have proper indexes available? Try to explain your select statement and check if it is using the indexes.

Comment: And include the results of the explain in the questions, so we can see.

Comment: Try calender left join receipts left join locations. or try to use calender first then remaining join.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT l.name location, c.date, COUNT(r.id) count
FROM calendar c
  left join calendar n on n.Date = c.Date + 1 -- one day after c.date
  left join (locations l join receipts r 
                on r.id like '%' + l.Id)
    on r.datetime between c.Date and n.Date
where c.Date between '2017-04-01' and '2017-04-07'
GROUP BY l.id, c.id
ORDER BY l.name,  c.date;
```

Your problem is caused by:
1.You were using a cross join which is unnecessary. Cross joins create Cartesian products (every row in one side is combined with every row on the other side.)  So cross joining the alphabet with the 10 digits will result in 260 rows, {A0, A1, A2...A9, B1, B2, ....B9 ...etc.}
2. the fact that there are multiple (although even one is enough) constructs in your SQL query that cause the query processor to have to read every row of the table from the disk, effectively preventing it from using any indices that might be on the table. Use of a function on a value of a column in a table for a filter (where clause) or for ordering (Order by clause) does this because the query processor cannot know what the functions value is without executing the function, and it must read the row from the main table on disk to get the underlying value to execute the function. If it was just the raw column value, and that column was in an index, the processor does not need to read the main data table, it can just traverse the index, which will often be a considerably smaller size and require a much smaller number of Disk IOs.

This is referred to as [SARGable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

if the `c.Date + 1` is not possible in MySQL, then try this:

```
SELECT l.name location, c.date, COUNT(r.id) count
FROM calendar c
  left join calendar n on n.Date = 
      (Select min(date) from Calendar -- subquery gets the next day in calendar
       Where date > c.Date)         
  left join (locations l join receipts r 
                on r.id like '%' + l.Id)
    on r.datetime between c.Date and n.Date
where c.Date between '2017-04-01' and '2017-04-07'
GROUP BY l.id, c.id
ORDER BY l.name,  c.date;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried the first query you posted but it still took a long time to run. However, I ended up solving this myself (see my answer). I had to move the where statement into both join subqueries which solved my issue. I suspect it's because it was no longer trying to join so many rows against an already large table of calendar dates. Limiting the result set to join solved the issue. I don't know enough about this to be sure that's why but hey it works!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    `locations`.`name` AS `location`,
    `calendar`.`date` AS `date`,
    COUNT(`receipts`.`id`) AS `count`
FROM `locations`
    CROSS JOIN `calendar`
    LEFT JOIN `receipts` ON `calendar`.`date` = DATE(`receipts`.`datetime`)
        AND `locations`.`id` = UPPER(LEFT(`receipts`.`id`, 1)) # there is no `location_id` FK. First char of receipts id is same as location id
WHERE `calendar`.`date` BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND  '2017-04-07'
GROUP BY `locations`.`id`, `calendar`.`id`
ORDER BY `locations`.`name` ASC, `calendar`.`date` ASC;
```

Try above query.

Here I had used `BETWEEN` instead of `<` and `>`.

Also you can create index on `calendar.date` this field.

You can add `FOREIGN KEY` constraint on child table and make join on that column. In that scenario also `INDEX` would be helpful .

Comment: The `BETWEEN` didn't speed it up. However, I ended up solving it myself (see answer). Thanks though.

Comment: `BETWEEN` is always equivalent to  `<=` and `>=` in performance.  (And not equivalent to `<` and `>` in functionality -- between is inclusive.)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I wasted everyone's time but I managed to solve this on my own.

Here is the query I figured out which runs instantly:

```
SELECT
    `l`.`name` AS `location`,
    `c`.`date` AS `date`,
    COUNT(`r`.`id`) AS `count`
FROM `locations` AS `l`
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT `calendar`.`id`, `calendar`.`date`
        FROM `calendar`
        WHERE `calendar`.`date` >= '2017-04-01' AND `calendar`.`date` <= '2017-04-07'
    ) `c`
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT `receipts`.`id`, `receipts`.`datetime`
        FROM `receipts`
        WHERE DATE(`receipts`.`datetime`) >= '2017-04-01' AND DATE(`receipts`.`datetime`) <= '2017-04-07'
    ) `r` ON `c`.`date` = DATE(`r`.`datetime`) AND `l`.`id` = UPPER(LEFT(`r`.`id`, 1))
GROUP BY `l`.`id`, `c`.`id`
ORDER BY `l`.`name` ASC, `c`.`date` ASC;
```